# Can de l'Hopital's rule be used in the case $\pm \frac{-\infty}{\infty}$?

Tags: derivatives

May de l'Hopital's rule be used (for $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$) if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = -\infty$ (or vice versa)? Wikipedia seems to be quite ambiguous as it says $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = \pm \infty $.

Comment: Short answer: yes. (Longer answer: there's some messiness in your hypothesis. If someone is keen, they can write it out more carefully.)

Comment: yes sorry i mean lim f(x) etc. edited it

Comment: yes, but why or why?

Comment: @abel what do you mean

Comment: never had to use l'hopitals.

Comment: @abel Congratulations on using only spanners and screwdrivers. Most of us don't mind using spanners, screwdrivers and hammers.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty$ then $\lim_{x \to a} -f(x) = -\infty$. Thus if you can prove that $$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{-f'(x)}{g'(x)} \text{ exists, and } g'(x)\not = 0 \text{ for $x$ in a neighbourhood around $a$ except possibly in $a$.}$$
L'Hopital's rule gives us that
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{-f(x)}{g(x)} =\lim_{x \to a} \frac{-f'(x)}{g'(x)} = -\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}
$$ 
Multiplying with -1 on both sides yields that
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}
$$